# Hosts file and Perl Mechanize

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I am trying to make a perl script to send a get request to applications I have created.  My applications are running on separate servers, so in order to make it seem like a domain, I added the ip's to my /etc/hosts file. My hosts file looks like:

```
10.1.10.50     test1.domain.com
10.1.10.51     test2.domain.com
```

When I run my script, which basically just does a get:

```
my $res = $mech->get("http://test1.domain.com/1");
```

I get the following error:

```
Error GETING http://test1.domain.com/1: test1.domain.com: unable to resolve
```

I am assuming that my perl script is not using my /etc/hosts file, is there anyway to make it check the hosts file for DNS or to setup domains in the program itself?

Thank you

Comment: What do you get from `perl -MSocket=inet_ntoa -E'my @h = gethostbyname($ARGV[0]); say inet_ntoa($_) for @h[4..$#h]' test1.domain.com`?

Comment: What do you get from `set | grep _proxy`? Did you tell LWP to use a proxy?

Comment: @ikegami 10.1.10.50 is the output.  I did not tell LWP to use a proxy, how do I do that.  The output to the second command is no_proxy=localhost, 127.0.0.0/8

Comment: Then I can't explain it.

Comment: Actually, what does `perl -MSocket -E'say inet_ntoa(inet_aton($ARGV[0]))' test1.domain.com` give?

Comment: Maybe running your script with `-d:Trace` will tell how the name is getting resolved.

Comment: That command also returns 10.1.10.50.  I will try running a trace and see what I can find out from that, thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Perl does not "use the /etc/hosts file".  It's using the same network stack as the rest of the machine.  It is the network layer that is using /etc/hosts.

Do those hostnames resolve from the shell?  What do they show?

Comment: Yes, I can ping test1.domain.com and test2.domain.com from my terminal.  I am using Ubuntu 12.04 server if that matters.